# Replacing blackboard bold in Classic Thesis

Tags: classicthesis

I want to use the `bbold` font for blackboard bold letters in my thesis using `classicthesis`. I can't seem to find a way to load the package in the options of `classicthesis` nor does loading `bbold` after `classicthesis` work. Is there any way to replace the blackboard font?

Here's what I'm trying to achieve:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{standalone}

\usepackage{classicthesis}
\usepackage{bbold}

\begin{document}
    $\mathbb{Z}$
\end{document}
```

This produces a $\mathbb{Z}$ in the font that `classicthesis` uses, rather than the one from `bbold`.